# Composing PartialFunctions with orElse when there is a wildcard case

Tags: scala, function-composition

Is it possible to `orElse` compose two `PartialFunction`s when the first function has `case _ =>` wildcard pattern that matches anything thus in effect being a total function.

For example, given

```
val pf1: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "foo"
  case 2 => "bar"
  case _ => "wildcard"
}

val pf2: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 3 => "baz"
  case _ => "wildcard"
}
```

then, out-of-the-box

```
(pf1 orElse pf2)(3)
```

outputs `wildcard`. However, assuming we cannot modify `pf1`, can we compose with `pf2` using some `compfn` such that we get in effect

```
{
  case 1 => "foo"
  case 2 => "bar"
  case 3 => "baz"
  case _ => "wildcard"
}
```

where `(pf1 compfn pf2)(3)` would output `baz`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can turn `pf1` into a true partial function by doing a second `match` to convert the "wildcard" result to a failed match.

```
val pf3: PartialFunction[Int, String] = (i: Int) => pf1(i) match {
  case s if s != "wildcard" => s
}
```

And then

```
(pf3 orElse pf2)(3)
```

If you want the precise syntax you showed then you need to use an implicit class:

```
implicit class addCompfn(f1: PartialFunction[Int, String]) {
  def compfn(f2: PartialFunction[Int, String]) = (i: Int) => f1(i) match {
    case s if s != "wildcard" => s
    case s => f2(i)
  }
}
```

And then

```
(pf1 compfn pf2)(3)
```

Comment: Well I was wrong! You've technically answered it correctly @Tim. Don't you both think that `"wildcard"` value should be parameterized to some `wildCardValue` in order to be more flexible? For example, https://scalafiddle.io/sf/fLc2Pdw/0

Comment: @BenjaminVialatou I think a predicate would be the best way to parameterise this. A fully generic solution would be templated on `[A, B]` and take a predicate `keep: B => Boolean` to decide which values to keep. `addCompfn` should also extend `AnyVal` for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Why not opting for something like this:

```
val pf1: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 1 => "foo"
  case 2 => "bar"
}

val pf2: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 3 => "baz"
}

def composeOrElseWildcard(input: Int) = (pf1 orElse pf2).applyOrElse(input,(_: Int) => "wildcard")
```

Otherwise, to me, there are no solution to get rid of wildcard pattern effect in `pf1`.

( `composeOrElseWildcard(3)` gives "baz" and `composeOrElseWildcard(4)` gives "wildcard" )